# AWS SFTP must allow users to download files with a specific tags in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, winscp

I am trying to do a simple task where in I must be able to download a file in `S3` which has a specific tag via `SFTP`. I am trying to achieve this by inserting a condition to the `SFTP` `IAM` Policy.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:ExistingObjectTag/key": "value"
            }
        } 
    }
]
```

}

But when I use this policy with the `SFTP` role, `WinSCP` throws permission denied error when I try to login to the server. I am able to login only if I remove the Condition part in the policy. If anyone knows how to do this, please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your IAM role works fine for GetObject. I was successfully able to assume a role that had your policy assigned. The issue must be related to SFTP, why don't you post an AWS support ticket. If you have already solved this problem, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restrict `GetObject` based on object tags.

IAM checks whether the user is entitled to make the request before it looks at the objects in Amazon S3 themselves. The tags are not available during this process.

Putting the objects in folders and restricting access by folder should meet your requirements.